# WebDriverIO no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, headless, google-chrome-headless

When I run tests locally on Windows 10 they work fine. All tests passed.
But when I do this on Jenkins I receive this error e.g.

`'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"app-header button i.mdi-gamburger-menu"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=70.0.3538.77)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 4.15.0-76-generic x86_64)' }`

My wdio.conf.js with browser config is next

```
capabilities: [{
    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
      args: ['headless', 'no-sandbox', 'disable-gpu', 'disable-dev-shm-usage', 'window-size=1920,1080']
    },
  }],
```

Could you tell what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: When you say Jenkins, is it executed against grid or in server? Jenkins is a ubuntu server?

Comment: server, ubuntu server ubuntu~18.04

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have problem with browser size,becouse you dont now browser size in remote machine.

At first try take screenshot from remote browser, you can attached screen to you report if use [allure](https://www.npmjs.com/package/allure-commandline) add to afterTest hook:

```
if (test.error !== undefined) {
      browser.takeScreenshot();
    }
```

Or just add `browser.takeScreenshot()` in line before falling, and download screen from remote machine.

If the problem is in browser size add `'--start-fullscreen'`, to you chrome args.